# Make a UIView zoomable

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview, uiscrollview, zooming

I am using the UIScrollView on iphone, and I want to be able to zoom on an UIView.

my UIView is a subview of ma uiscrollview. If I return the view, when I tried to zoom, my view move but dont zoom :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

//mon label peut prendre la valeur de mon menu
[monLabel setText:monMenu];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(1, 1, 320, 480); // Replacing with your dimensions
maVue = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
maVue.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 480);
scrollView.bounces = YES;
//scrollView.bouncesZoom = YES;
scrollView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
//scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
//scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5.0;
scrollView.delegate = self;
[scrollView addSubview:maVue];

 }

 - (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView
 *)scrollView{  return maVue; }
```

if I replace my view by a label for exemple :

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

//mon label peut prendre la valeur de mon menu
[monLabel setText:monMenu];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(1, 1, 320, 480); // Replacing with your dimensions
maVue = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
maVue.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 480);
scrollView.bounces = YES;
//scrollView.bouncesZoom = YES;
scrollView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
//scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
//scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5.0;
scrollView.delegate = self;
[scrollView addSubview:monLabel];

 }

 - (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView
 *)scrollView{  return monLabel; }
```

the zoom works well. My label magnified.

Do you have any idea why it's working for a label but not for an UIView?

thanks

Do you

Answer (score 0):

Did you implement `scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale:`? I also noticed that you commented out the code initializing `minimumZoomScale` and `maximumZoomScale`. Better to set that correctly.

From the [UIScrollView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html):

> For zooming and panning to work, the
>   delegate must implement **both**
>   `viewForZoomingInScrollView:` and
>   `scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale:`;
>   in addition, the maximum
>   (maximumZoomScale) and minimum (
>   minimumZoomScale) zoom scale **must be different**.

Comment: I commented the code initializing minimumZoomScale and maximumZoomScale, I have initialized with IB.

Comment: I have also implement the implement scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale: with nothing inside. But I don't understand why it's working for the label but not for the UIView

Comment: Ok, I just found the problem, it's something stupid. Thank Atlealice for your help

Comment: Ok, good thing you found it. :). I've had a fair share of facepalm bugs in objective-c myself, so don't let it get to you much. ^_^